# Need a solenoid to pull a Nerf Gun trigger

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid, electromagnetic

I'm looking for a solenoid  that be used to pull the trigger of a Nerf gun.  Using a strain gauge I determined that you need about 1 kg of force to pull the trigger, and the travel of the trigger is about 17 mm.  I have a solid understanding of general voltage and current basics, but never worked with solenoids or magnetism in general.

I've been looking at solenoids on Digi-Key.  They seem to be rated by voltage, stroke length and power (in watts).  They also rate it by DC Resistance (in ohms) and lots of other things.  [Here's](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/delta-electronics/DSOL-1341-12/1144-1309-ND/5214000) an example.

From these numbers, how do I determine if a particular solenoid will be able to generate the force I need?

I've also considered purchasing some enameled magnet wire and making my own.  But I have no idea what gauge wire I would need and how much I would need.  If someone coud help me with the math, that'd be great.

Comment: 1kg ... and 17 mm... I'm not sure you want to know what that solenoid looks like. The linked one's datasheet shows it's at 250W and still falls short (about 7N at 17mm). Consider one of the larger RC model servos instead.

Comment: you could try an automotive starter solenoid

Comment: @BrianDrummond how did you determine that it puts out 7N at 17mm?

Comment: Totally agree with @BrianDrummond, The RC Servo is the way to go here. Reasonable cost, reasonable size and torque range available. Controlling it would be dependent upon factors not clear at this point.

Comment: I looked at the graph in the datasheet, labelled Force(N) on the Y axis.

Comment: You can charge a capacitor and dump that into the solenoid if the repetition isn't too fast.

Comment: If you need repetitive firing, a solenoid is a poor choice. If you just need to fire once, you could make a spring-loaded mechanism that is cocked by hand, then a hair trigger is controlled by a smaller solenoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why a solenoid might not work

Solenoids in this situation would probably not be ideal. From my experience solenoids have great holding force, but not that strong initial force, so it may not be able to supply the needed 1Kg of force to get the trigger pushed. I have used beefy solenoids that run on high voltage and they have shown to be weak right at the start of motion to the point where you can hold the shaft in without much effort at all

## Alternative control methods

A better alternative as some have already mentioned are rc servo motors, which depending on which one you get could definitely supply the needed force, and are easy to program with an arduino, as well as they run on low voltages depending on the one you get. Another alternative is a linear actuator which are available in many different forms. The simplest way would be attaching a motor to a screw (keeping positioning in mind) such as a stepper motor. Or there are already made linear actuators that have their own internal limit switches and all they need are a reversible DC current to control them. (using something like an H-bridge circuit). Despite those two as sticking out as the most obvious to me, there are definitely more ways to go about it.

## Diy solenoid

Despite the issues with solenoids as stated previously, creating one from scratch is a hassle. Finding/making a good core, winding it up, only to realize that you too much wire, or that the resistance is too high for your application. I'm not sure as to the open-endedness of your project but from experience sticking commercial for something like a solenoid is usually the way to go.

## Alternative Triggering Methods

Besides finding more ways to pull the trigger, replacing the trigger mechanism itself might be an option. Look on youtube and you will see plenty of videos of teardowns of your nerf gun. Once you see what is inside and making the trigger mechanism work it may occur that it is easier to just modify the trigger mechanism itself.

I'm not sure on size, voltage, or current limitations for your project so I don't want to go looking for specific items to recommend just for it to be too big or too power consuming. Good luck!

Comment: A gearmotor with a crank and a limit switch may work -- just drive the motor unconditionally for a set time, then let it continue to run until it hits the limit.

Comment: @TimWescott yes that is another valid idea. Many solutions to this problem

Comment: Thanks everyone for chasing me off the idea of a solenoid.  Indeed, a high-torque servo motor did the trick.

Comment: @J-bob Glad to hear it worked out!